# What does "a good deal" mean ? Are there some suitable alternatives for it?

Tags: meaning

What does "a good deal" mean?

> A: The dinner special is only $6.99.
>
> B: That sounds like **a good deal**.

Is it true that this would be the meaning?

> It sounds like an economical choice.

Are there some suitable alternatives for it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common use of "a good deal" is to mean "An indefinite quantity or amount; a lot" ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/deal)).

However, in your context, this is a different definition of "deal" (also in Wiktionary):

> 3. A particular instance of buying or selling, a transaction
> 4. Specifically, a transaction offered which is financially beneficial; a bargain.

Alternatives:

> That sounds like a bargain.
>   That sounds like a good price.